# Cisco ASA static nat one-to-many from interface address to object-group

Tags: cisco-asa, nat

*Syntactically*, the following set of statements is valid (at least as of 8.3):

```
interface Ethernet0/0
  nameif OUTSIDE
  ip address 192.0.2.1 255.255.255.0
interface Ethernet0/1
  nameif INSIDE
  ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0

object network O_N_EXAMPLE1
  host 10.1.1.2
object network O_N_EXAMPLE2
  host 10.1.1.3
object service O_S_EXAMPLE1
  service tcp destination eq 60001
object service O_S_EXAMPLE2
  service tcp destination eq 60002
object-group network OG_N_EXAMPLEHOSTS
  network-object object O_N_EXAMPLE1
  network-object object O_N_EXAMPLE2

nat (OUTSIDE,INSIDE) source static any any destination static interface OG_N_EXAMPLEHOSTS service O_S_EXAMPLE1 O_S_EXAMPLE2

nat (INSIDE,OUTSIDE) after-auto source dynamic any interface
```

The second `nat` statement is fairly obvious -- it simply translates everything outbound to the WAN IP, in a typical hide-NAT/LAN-to-WAN scenario.

However, the *first* `nat` defines a (probably invalid) rule directing any inbound request for the WAN IP over TCP/60001 to be sent to either of 192.0.2.1:60002 or 192.0.2.2:60002.

The ASA command-line lets you enter it without error.

`packet-tracer` doesn't balk at it (at least, assuming an `access-group` permits):

- `packet-tracer input OUTSIDE tcp 192.0.2.100 12345 192.0.2.1 60001` "succeeds", in that it says the final action is to *allow*, and along the way it untranslates to 10.1.1.2 and identifies the output interface as `INSIDE`.
- `packet-tracer input INSIDE tcp 10.1.1.1 60002 192.0.2.1 60002` "succeeds", in that it says the final action is to *allow*, and along the way it translates to 192.0.2.1, but does not indicate the ouput interface.

What it does *not* do (and what I think might have been the original intent) is distribute between the two target IPs, nor *track* which of the two hosts is up and establish a translation to an available node.  I don't *believe* that ASA has any function for that (although I'm happy to be proved wrong!) beyond tracked routes, which are more to do with outbound, LAN-to-multi-WAN traffic.

In practice I expect it accepts the inbound and drops the reply traffic, resulting in a failed TCP handshake.

I note that splitting the `nat` statement into two statements results in an ovelap [sic] warning:

```
# nat (OUTSIDE,INSIDE) source static any any destination static interface O_N_EXAMPLE1 service O_S_EXAMPLE1 O_S_EXAMPLE2
# nat (OUTSIDE,INSIDE) source static any any destination static interface O_N_EXAMPLE2 service O_S_EXAMPLE1 O_S_EXAMPLE2
WARNING: mapped-address 192.0.2.2/60002-0 ovelap with existing static NAT.
```

So I wonder, **how does the ASA interpret that first `nat` statement and, in particular, under what circumstances would it actually attempt to translate to 10.1.1.3?**

I understand what would happen if the NAT was a `destination static` between two `object` objects (a simple translation from the first to the second) or even two `object-group` objects with the same number of `network-object` entries (a one-to-one translation from the *n*th entry in the first group to the *n*th entry in the second group), but not in this case, with a one-to-many definition.

Does it just translate between the interface address and the first `network-object`, dicarding the second?  Or does it work something out with regards to available ephemeral ports (e.g. the first 64K connections go to 192.0.2.1 and the second go to 192.0.2.2)?  Does it duplicate the traffic to both?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the ASA does not track NAT objects to direct packets to objects that are "up".  You are also correct that it does not load balance or share translations between hosts (at least when the NAT type is "static").  It also does not split the ports into pools and allocate them among objects.

The answer is contained here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa91/configuration/firewall/asa_91_firewall_config/nat_overview.html#13402

> For a many-to-few or many-to-one configuration, where you have more real addresses than mapped addresses, you run out of mapped addresses before you run out of real addresses. Only the mappings between the lowest real IP addresses and the mapped pool result in bidirectional initiation. The remaining higher real addresses can initiate traffic, but traffic cannot be initiated to them (returning traffic for a connection is directed to the correct real address because of the unique 5-tuple (source IP, destination IP, source port, destination port, protocol) for the connection).

What happens is that the ASA iterates the "translated" object/object-group until it gathers the correct quantity of hosts to satisfy the untranslated object/object-group.  In your case above, the necessary quantity is 1.  To the best of my understanding, under no circumstances will traffic be translated to 10.1.1.3 based upon the configuration above, until someone removes 10.1.1.2 from `object-group network OG_N_EXAMPLEHOSTS`.

Regarding your experiment where you split the NAT into two, I just wanted to add a little clarity.  Despite that the ASA gave you an overlap warning, I believe it does accept the command and add it to the config and the NAT table.  Manual NATs (or "twice NATs" as sometimes they are called) are processed in top-down, first-match order.  So the second statement would never be hit.  It is possible to reorder manual NAT rules.

As a closing thought, there is an alternate way to configure this NAT.

```
object network O_N_EXAMPLE1
 nat (INSIDE,OUTSIDE) static interface service tcp 60002 60001
```

and if you also attempted the following . . .

```
object network O_N_EXAMPLE2
 nat (INSIDE,OUTSIDE) static interface service tcp 60002 60001
```

. . . then it would also be added to the Auto NAT table following NAT Rule Order (https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa91/configuration/firewall/asa_91_firewall_config/nat_overview.html#31590) and it would only be hit in the outbound direction (which will never happen since the server will not likely initiate a connection sourcing from a port where it has a listening daemon).